# How to disable the code for auto-updating the region from the page in the apex oracle?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a code for auto-updating the region, this iodine is immersed in the panel "Execute when Page Loads":

```html
  setInterval ( "jQuery ('#report_modified'). trigger ('apexrefresh');" , '10000' );
```

this code works. But I want to make sure that I can disable this automatic update from the page. That is, I want to uncheck and stop updating.Can anyone help me with this ??
I tried so, but it doesn't work when changing the state of a variable. And I don't know what to do

```html
 if($v('P91_AUTOUPDT') == 'true'){
    setInterval ( "jQuery ('#report_modified'). trigger ('apexrefresh');" ,'1000' );
            
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place to start is the docs. setInterval takes a callback function and an interval. So eval the condition in the function and you're good to go. Change the code to:

```
setInterval ( function(){
     if (apex.item( "P91_AUTOUPDT" ).getValue() === 'true') {
         $('#report_modified').trigger('apexrefresh');
     }
} , '10000' );
```

This works fine for me.